# Can you Create a Keynote using the Revit API in C#

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I'm trying to create a Keynote Tag via the Revit 2012 API.  However, I found now reference to creating a Keynote Tag anywhere on the internet or in the samples.  I see that the BuiltInCategory.OST_KeynoteTags is part of the IndependentTag class and according to http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/files/guide-to-placing-family-instances-with-the-api.doc you need to use the TM_ADDBY_CATEGORY TagMode to create a Keynote.  However, when you then try to change the new Tag via ChangeTypeId, you get an error.

Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revit API: How to create Element Keynote for a wall and Material Keynote?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589221/revit-api-how-to-create-element-keynote-for-a-wall-and-material-keynote)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to try yet, but I'm thinking you're out of luck.
For the most part, you can't do things with the API that you can't do interactively in Revit.  I did quickly test that you can't change the type of a multi-category tag to be a keynote tag.
While they're both `IndependentTag` elements, they are different Categories, and it's very rare in my experience where you can switch the category of a placed element.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I assumed that it wasn't possible, but never saw any documentation that it wasn't, or was, possible.  For my purpose I was able to just renumber existing keynotes in a view.  Perhaps you could just copy an existing keynote?  Maybe I'll look into that someday.