# Revit API: How to create Element Keynote for a wall and Material Keynote?

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I'm trying to create Element Keynote for a wall and Material Keynote for it's materials (to make it like [in this image](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/media/gallerypage/user-id/1240000/image-id/52414iD032159FA2052B0E) bit I'm completely stuck with it.

I tried to create a tag how it was shown in this blog post: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/set-tag-type.html But I can't change a keynote tag to `OST_KeynoteTags` and to associate it with wall or material:

```
FamilySymbol keynoteTagType = GetFirstFamilySymbol(doc, BuiltInCategory.OST_KeynoteTags);
IndependentTag newTag = doc.Create.NewTag(view, wall, true, tagMode, tagorn, wallMid);
```

but Revit doesn't allow me to do this:

```
newTag.ChangeTypeId(keynoteTagType.Id);
```

or maybe I'm on the wrong path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I got from Autodesk is that it's impossible to create keynotes via the API.

Sorry to break the bad news.